# Mechanics of Invasion

Tags: dark-souls-2

Today I've been invaded for the first time and I kept being invaded for quite some time after that, in succession. In the beginning only one invader came and he was killed. Another one came and I killed him too. The third time two invaders came and I died. At this point I thought no one would come anymore but I was wrong. The fourth time two invader came and I managed to kill them both. The fifth time a single invader was sent back with his ass kicked. At this point I burned a human effigy because I wanted to fight the boss of the area. This made me wonder why I was never invaded before and out of the blue an horde of invaders came to my world.
At that point I've never invaded anyone.

Another weird thing is that even tho I'm in the "Way of Blue" covenant and wearing the ring I was never helped. Do I have to do something (other than what I did already) in order to summon a blue ghost? Do the blue sentinels need to just wear the ring in order to be automatically summoned or they need to use the blue orb? Does the area I'm in affects invasion/help (ie: blue sentinels can be summoned even if we actually are in two different areas from the game?)

My question is: what's the mechanic of invasion? Is there something I can do to lower/increment the change to be invaded? How can I summon blue ghost if I'm invaded?

It may seems a lot of questions but they are all related to the same topic: How does the invasion system work?

Comment: The invasion system is extremely complicated, any answer to this would seem to fall under a 'list' type question http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3714/list-questions-for-the-old-republic-mmos-cw-closure-other/3722#3722

Comment: well, idk, that's pretty specific. I'm not asking for the list of all weapons in the game or something like that.

Comment: In which zone were you ? Some are more prone to invasions for covenant-related reasons, and it sounds a lot like you were in Belfry Luna.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that just yesterday. Nice guess tho :-)

Comment: I'm horrible when someone invades me. I get very anxious. Those are the reasons I joined the Way of the Blue covenant; so I would have help from the blue sentinels. I've been invaded about 15 times and no one has ever come to help me. I've always had my ring on, but not on human form, I save the effigies for boss fights. I've heard some people say that you must be human to get the help. So does that mean as you are being invaded you hurry up and down an effigy? It's very frustrating and I appreciate any and all help. PSNid: BellaBAE

Answer (score 5):

I'm a blue knight and yes I have to wear my ring for you to summon me and you must be in human form with your ring on to summon me. I've been summon from random places all across the map, even to areas I hadn't yet been too. The only place I wasn't summon to was the bell tower as that was a pvp area for the protectors of the bell covenant. If you were in that area, if you weren't human, if you weren't wearing the ring and one of us wasn't wearing our ring, that is why you couldn't summon one of us.

As for summoning and invasion 
The way it worked in dark souls 1 and dark souls 2 are different to make it more fair. It depends both on soul level and soul memory. Your soul level is what level you are while your soul memory is based off of how souls you spent on your armor weapon and levels. You can find it in your player status menu. It's to help fight against over powered people fighting under powered people.

Hope this helps and praise the sun.

Answer (score -1):

To fully understand how Invasions worked, I started invading other players. Apparently, I invaded a Level 6 player with my level 38 priest. If that is the case, the system for invading doesn't rely on level or soul memory. Of all of the times I invaded, only once did a Blue Sentinel came to help. Not sure if the world master was alive or not. Since you are saying that you got invaded by more than one player, I can guess you were inside the Bell Tower, where the Guardians can't help. Keep an eye out for the colors of the phantoms: Grey are from covenants like the Bell Tower or Rat Covenant, while Red are Invading players looking for blood. You don't need to wear the Ring for Guardians to come help you while in Way of Blue Covenant. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

Pretty much what user73398 said. I know for a fact that once you hit a certain soul memory/level in certain areas you get invaded. I also noticed that it doesn't matter what the invaders soul memory or level is. If I'm mistaken, then the invaders I've faced are hackers. I know this because I've been invaded twice in Heide's Tower of Flames at the first bonfire you light from Majula and both times I was 1 hit killed. Once by a sorcerer and another by a sword+shield wielder. Knowing I had 250k soul memory at level 57, knowing that, there's absolutely NO possible way for either character of my level and soul memory range could EVER 1 shot 1k HP. So it either doesn't matter for invaders or I've been extremely unlucky and they were cheaters.

Comment: Actually you are wrong. I did 1100 backstab damage with my mastodon halberd at SL 60 when I was invading people. Get your facts straight. (and it was only +8). And about the sorcerer, there are some seriously heavy hiting spells. Especially the hexes that cost souls to cast.

Comment: Actually they are correct. I've been invaded at sould level 20k by people that we (I have 2 people I party with alot of the time) couldn't damage at all no matter what we did. So there are either some very buggy matching systems or there are quite a few hackers out there that like to mess up peoples games.